# Moving ChromeVox focus from menu div to content div

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-navigation

I am working with the ChromeVox extension to add a text reader for our church web site www.uulynchburg.org. When using the mouse to navigate, it is easy to click on a text block to start the reader.  The problem comes for someone unable to use the mouse and relying on navigation keys.  I can walk down the menu, but once a menu item is selected, I want the focus to jump from the memu  to the start of the text in the content .

Comment: Could you attach some codes about the issue?

Comment: The web page is [link](http://www.uulynchburg.org) with a menu division <div id="leftMenuCol" class="leftMenu"> and a content devision <div id="mainContent" class="mainContent">.

Comment: Having learned a little more, if I use header tags <Hn> at the top of each division, the user can jump to the next or previous header. See [chromevox keyboard](http://www.chromevox.com/keyboard_shortcuts.html) for a list of key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus ChromeVox on a particular page element, you need to focus on that element.

1. **Create a wrapper element which is focusable.**

   To make inherently un-focusable elements (non-form elements, buttons, links, etc) focusable, add `tab-index="-1"`.)

   ```
   <div id="main-content" tab-index="-1">
     <h1>heading</h1>
   </div>
   ```
2. **Use javascript to focus on the element** after navigating, on page load, or whatever event makes most sense.

   ```
   document.getElementById('main-content').focus()
   ```

This is an example but you can select any specific element.

This technique is especially useful if you are building a single-page-app.